# React: Uncaught TypeError: X is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I am trying to render a button in a react-table column. If I refactor the button to its own component, it complains that `it's not a function`.

Top level (ExampleReactTable.js):

```
const handleClick = () => setIsOpen(true);

const columns = getTableColumns(handleClick);
```

Middle layer (getTableColumns.js):

```
Cell: () => <ExampleButton handleClick={() => handleClick()} />
```

Botton layer (ExampleButton.js):

```
const ExampleButton = handleClick => {
  console.log(handleClick);
  return (
    <Box>
      <Button variation="text" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
        Click
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

This errors out with `handleClick is not a function`.

If I don't refactor the button out, it works:

```
Cell: () => (
        <Box>
          <Button variation="text" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
            Click
          </Button>
        </Box>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not destructuring props, because the function received the props as an object, which you are passing to onclick as a function, resulting in the error, try this:

```js
const ExampleButton = ({handleClick}) => {
  console.log(handleClick);
  return (
    <Box>
      <Button variation="text" onClick={() => handleClick()}>
        Click
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

This is the same as:

```js
const ExampleButton = (props) => {
  console.log(handleClick);
  return (
    <Box>
      <Button variation="text" onClick={() => props.handleClick()}>
        Click
      </Button>
    </Box>
  );
};
```